# Android empty bar on top of the keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I need help and i'm hoping someone knows a solution. I have a textfield in my app with disabled suggestions and no microphone icon -> without any bar over the keys.
It works like a charm, until i change the keyboard to the numbers and special characters (Screen below). There is an empty bar on top of the keyboard. Do i have a chance to have the keyboard without the bar at all views? (Android 6.0.1)

My code of the textfield:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/without_gb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:privateImeOptions="nm"/>
```

[image: Keyboard with strange empty bar on top]

I already tried adjustPan and adjustResize... nothing worked:(

Answer (score 1):

THis is most certainly a bug or intended behaviour of this specific soft-keyboard. You should not rely on the users keyboard, every device might have another keyboard installed or activated. Do not try to fix the problem with text-input inside your app, declare your inputs as desired and rely on the keyboard implementation to do the rest. Any kind of workaround or hack might break your application for other input methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed it could be a bug of this android version or device. Sadly that ist the stock Android keyboard on a Nexus 7 with stock Android.
I would like to follow your hint to rely on the implementaion, but the empty bar ist not really a thing i want to be in the app at all... (i like beautiful apps :D)

Comment: That empty Bar is not a Part of your App, its the Keyboards Way of saying suggestions are turned Off!